# Bluetooth headset overiding ringtones?

Tags: bluetooth-audio, motorola-moto-z2-play

My Bluetooth headset (SoundBuds Rise) will play its own generic ringtone when it's connected to my phone (Moto Z2 Play). I just went through and gave a bunch of my contacts custom ringtones, so I don't have to pull my phone out to look at who is calling. Is there anyway to force my headset to use my ringtone instead of its?